# Is it possible to create a timer that skips a function within a loop?

Tags: c++, timer, c++-chrono, chronometer

In my project I'm using opencv to catch frames from a webcam and detect some things in there through some functions. The problem is that in a determinate function is not necesary to catch all the frames, it would be enough to take a frame every 0.5 seconds for example and if the time has not finished, the loop continue to the next function. The idea in code would be:

```
while(true){
  //read(frame)
  //cvtColor(....)
  // and other things
  time = 0;// start time
  if (time == 0.5){
      determinatefunction(frame, ...)
  }else {
      continue;
  }
  //some others functions
}
```

I tried to do something similar to the above with the chrono library:

```
// steady_clock example
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void foo(){
cout << "printing out 1000 stars...\n";
  for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i) cout << "*";
  cout << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    steady_clock::time_point t1 = steady_clock::now();
    int i = 0;
    while(i <= 100){
        cout << "Principio del bucle" << endl;
        steady_clock::time_point t2 = steady_clock::now();
        duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
        cout << time_span.count() << endl;
        if (time_span.count() == 0.1){
            foo();
            steady_clock::time_point t1 = steady_clock::now();
        }else {
            continue;
        }
        cout << "fin del bucle" << endl;
        i++;
    }
}
```

But the loop never ends and never start foo() function.

I can't use posix thread(I saw the function sleep_for) because i'm using g++ (x86_64-win32-sjlj-rev4, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2 and its works with opencv 2.4.9. I try to implement mingw posix with opencv but it give me errors that do not make sense like `'VideoCapture' was not declared in this scope VideoCapture cap(0)` when the includes and libs are written correctly.

I'using windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `==` in combination with floating point calculations is most of the time wrong.

There is no guarantee that `duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1)` will be executed when the difference is exactly `0.1`.

Instead it might be something like `0.099324`  and in the next iteration `0.1000121`

Use `>=`  instead and defining another `t1`  within the `if`  does not make much sense.

```
if (time_span.count() >= 0.1) {
  foo();
  t1 = steady_clock::now();
}
```